# Partial match 2 sheets results in adjacent cell data

Tags: excel

In Excel I am trying to compare partial match in a column from sheet 1 with a column sheet 2 and then put the adjacent values from the partial match in sheet 2 into a column on sheet1.

So far I have `=VLOOKUP($C$1:$C$337&"*",RetouchersTime!$A$2:$A$104,2,FALSE)`

I have revised to this: =INDEX(RetouchersTime!$A:$A, MATCH(""&C7&"",RetouchersTime!$B:$B,0)) and still do not receive the result I am looking for.

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51050869/edit) your question instead of adding information as comments -- it makes it hard to track things otherwise

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say from just what you wrote.  Isn't False an exact match? You could try index matching too.  A lot of people like it better.  Not sure if that helps, but maybe it's a start.